# how to use list syntax with defaults spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

I am attempting to parse comma separated integers, with possible blanks.  For instance, `1,2,,3,,-1` should be parsed as `{1,2,n,3,n,-1}`  where is `n` is some constant.

The expression,

```
(int_ | eps) % ','
```

works when `n == 0`.  More specifically, the following code works special cased for `0`:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   using namespace boost::qi;
   std::vector<int> v;
   std::string s("1,2,,3,4,,-1");
   phrase_parse(s.begin(), s.end(), 
      (int_|eps) % ','
      , space, v);
}
```

I tried the following expression for arbitrary `n`:

```
(int_ | eps[_val = 3]) % ','
```

But apparently this is wrong.  The compiler generates an error novel.  I refrain from pasting all that here, as most likely what I am trying is incorrect (rather than specific compiler issues).

What would be the right way?

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `attr()` parser exists for this purpose:

```
(int_ | attr(3)) % ','
```